How do I use the `append-to` parameter in the `element-plus` `element-select` component? Why does the parameter I specified not take effect?
I'm currently working on a project using VueFlow, which can implement workflow arrangements. In the canvas, nodes can be generated by dragging and dropping them from the left side to the right side, as shown in the figure.
ISSUE
When the canvas on the right side is zoomed in or out, the dropdown menu in the nodes on the left side cannot be scaled together with the canvas.
I hope that when the canvas on the right side is zoomed in or out, the selectors inside the nodes can be scaled at the same time.
Therefore, I looked at the documentation of el-select and initially judged that the reason for this is that the dropdown of el-select is added below the body element, and the elements supported for zooming on the right side are the VueFlow div and its child elements. By hanging the dropdown of el-select on the body element, the right-side zooming is not supported. Therefore, we can cancel the hanging of the dropdown of el-select on the body node by using the teleported parameter, and then hang it on the target div we want by using the append-to parameter. I tried setting the append-to parameter to the ref reference of the target div, but an error was generated, saying that there was a problem with the parameter setting. How can we achieve the above requirement?
enter image description here


  <el-table-column label="选择条件" width="17%">
                        <template #default="scope">
                          <el-form-item
                              prop="condition"
                          >

                              <el-select
                                  v-model="scope.row.condition"
                                  style="margin-right: 6px"
                                  :teleported="false"
                                  :append-to="viewportRef"
                              >
                                <el-option
                                    v-for="item in contitionTypeOption"
                                    :key="item"
                                    :label="item"
                                    :value="item"
                                    :title="item"
                                />
                              </el-select>
                          </el-form-item>
                        </template>
                      </el-table-column>
<template>
  <div ref="viewportRef" class="vue-flow__viewport vue-flow__container">
    <Pane
      :is-selecting="isSelecting"
      :selection-key-pressed="selectionKeyPressed"
      :class="{ connecting: !!connectionStartHandle, dragging: paneDragging, draggable: shouldPanOnDrag }"
    >
      <Transform>
        <slot />
      </Transform>
    </Pane>
  </div>
</template>



